# Add MonoTouch.Dialog to an MonoTouch project (Not windows)

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

With the patch today to MonoDevelop all my projects were corrupted and I've had to rebuild them.

How do I add MonoTouch.Dialog to a project?  I'm pretty sure I'd right click the References, click Edit References and then click in the Packages and find the one labeled something like MonoTouch.Dialog, but I cannot find it anymore.

What is it labeled (now)?  Or do I have to download MonoTouch.Dialog from Github?

That last is a joke, because MonoTouch.Dialog-1.dll is still in the 2.1 folder

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MonoTouch.Dialog should be in the All tab in the Edit References dialog:

[image]

Comment: It isn't - nor is monotouch as in your picture.  Nor is MonoTouch.NUinitLite either.

Comment: What are the system references on the right side?  You have something labeled mono... what is that?  I don't have that, maybe that is what I'm missing.

Comment: mono => monotouch. That said, I believe something is not right at all about your MonoDevelop install, you shouldn't be having these types of problems in the first place. Exactly which version of MonoDevelop did you install? What does "About MonoDevelop" show?

Comment: And which version of MonoTouch do you have? These assemblies actually come from MonoTouch.

Comment: Yes, I got a patch today and it screwed my projects.  I had to rebuild them all - yes I paid the 400 for it.

Comment: About MonoDevelop shows 3.0.1 - don't know how to find MonoTouch version.  But I think its 5.3.3

Comment: @ChuckSavage: This looks like a serious bug and I suggest you file it here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com where it will be tracked properly.

Comment: Not quite sure what was wrong, but through talking to Nat (everyone else was on the phone and he picked up) he was able to talk me through it.  I'd done a couple re-installs, so something got fixed that wasn't noticeable until an expert was able to walk me through as I said. Thanks for the help.  I'm gonna mark this as the answer, as its the only one and the post can't be deleted.  Thanks again.